# Spring security default ignores j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, nginx

I'm tryinmg to reassemble my spring mvc application to use it with nginx server. Not just for serving static pages to. All was seem fine to me, but suddenly i faced problem, that default UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  that must check /j_spring_security_check url does nothing. Just passing that link through.
Here is my web.xml - as you can see - it's common;

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <description>Web server of secure</description>

    <!-- Start root service context -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/service-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Setup servlet context-->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Setup spring security -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my security-context and servlet-context that includes security

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <!--login-page="/api/account/login"-->
    <description>Security layer</description>

    <security:http auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true"
                   authentication-manager-ref="daoBasedAuthManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/account/checklogin" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/account/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/account/register" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/account/toregister" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/account/tovalidateToken" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/account/validateToken" access="isAnonymous()"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/header.html" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/footer.html" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:form-login  login-page="/api/account/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />

    </security:http>

    <bean id ="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/api/account/home"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
                </bean>
                <!--<bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>-->
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <security:authentication-manager  id="daoBasedAuthManager" erase-credentials="false" >
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthProvider"/>

    </security:authentication-manager>
    <bean id="userService" class="ua.secure.service.UserServiceImpl"/>
    <bean id="customAuthProvider" class="ua.secure.service.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager id="predefinedAuthManager" >
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

servlet-context.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <description>Web layer</description>

    <import resource="security-context.xml"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.secure.web"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
                <property name="location">
                    <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
                </property>
            </bean>

</beans>
```

And finally, my log, when im trying to login
[LOG](http://pastebin.com/VNbyzgzk)
This is log from my app, that lies on tomcat completely
[LOG from working app](http://pastebin.com/yxbiDsVs)

As you can see, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter should react on j_spring_security_check

UPD
And this is my login form

```html
    <div id="loginform">
    <form action="/SecurConfig/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
        <div class="loginparamtext">email:</div>
        <input class="text" type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"/>

        <div class="loginparamtext">password:</div>
        <input class="text" type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"/>

        <div class="loginparamtext">Remember me
            <input style="width:50px;" type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me'/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

**UPD**
I changed form action="/SecurConfig/j_spring_security_check" to just

> form action="/j_spring_security_check"

and in began top work;

Comment: I haven't check your config carefully yet, but I think with this config, you are using ua.secure.service.UserServiceImpl to provide user credentials? Note that the code is using daoBasedAuthManager, NOT predefinedAuthManager.

Comment: Yes, predefinedAuthManager is just in case if i cant acess my DB somehow. App is using daoBasedAuthManager